# Get Element ID and passing into function

Tags: php, javascript

I'm using javascript to get my element id value. But out of 3, one of my element id does not parse in. It gives me [object HTMLInputElement] while the rest of element id values can work.

Sample Code:

```
<?php 
$Name = "Johnnnny";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"Name\" id=\"Name\" value=\"$Name\"/>";
?>
 <script>
  var ID= document.getElementById('ID').value; //this works.
  var Name = document.getElementById('Name').value; //give me [object HTMLInputElement]
 </script>
```

Kindly advise. It should be able to get the ElementID of 'Name'.value

Comment: This isn't all of your code. Please post the rest. `Name` may be overwritten somewhere else.

Comment: consider not using variable names like ID, Name, and value to avoid confusion with constants in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your `<input>` element inside a `<form>`

You seem to have your ids confused. Getting an ElementById returns a DOM element that has an id attribute set to the value you've supplied.

so if I have something like this:

```
<form id="theform">
    <input type="hidden" name="Name" id="Name" value="Johnny"/>
</form>
```

doing something like this:

```
 document.getElementById('theform')
```

would return the form and this:

```
 var iname = document.getElementById('Name')
```

would return the hidden input. Now you can access the attributes of the hidden input like this: `iname.value` [returns the value]  or  `iname.name`  [returns the name]

Additionally, like stated by somebody else this cannot be all of your code, because `document.getElementById('ID')` would return nothing (null) and you would get an error.